# Why unique constraints delete the existing data in Janusgraph used with cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have added unique constraints to my databases as said in the documentation.
Lets say I have run the following

```
g.V().has('name',"myname")
```

I received the vertex id.

But When I again add a vertex as follows

```
g.addV("myvertex").has("name","myname")
```

results Unique constraint failed error , which is good and desired.
But when I tried the following again , I didn't get the vertex id. Unique contraints removes the original data too.

```
g.V().has('name',"myname")
```

I am using cassandra 4.0 and janusgraph 6.0

Comment: When you created the property initially did you commit that transaction? If not, after a time, it will rollback.

Comment: So, each time I 'll add a vertex I have to commit,right?

Comment: With Janus Graph you need to periodically commit the transaction that is automatically started when you issue a query,. If you do not, the changes will be rolled back when the transaction times out.